# Booting Linux (rootfs) on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, root

Let's say I have Linux on USB (Ubuntu Debian 6, Kernel 2.6) and I want to boot it on my Windows 10. How would I do it?

Folder structure is like this:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrnOz.png)

Comment: You don't boot one OS on another.  If you don't need concurrent access to both OSes and want each to have access to the full resources, you dual boot, which is one or the other.  If you need them both at the same time, you can set one up as a virtual machine inside the other.  Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: I meant Live Boot, not boot one on another. But I'm not sure how would I Live Boot - that's my problem.

Comment: A Linux live session doesn't care about Windows.  You may need a third party utility like UNetbootin or Rufus to put the boot provision on the USB drive (not needed if you use a DVD).  And it will need to reflect UEFI.  There are tons of tutorials online.  Have you run into a specific issue?

Comment: Yes, the Rufus says 'Failed to scan image' when I choose rootfs as image.

Comment: Sounded like you were talking about the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) for a second